# ts/react - fetch in useEffect gets called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch

in my functional component I want to fetch data once the component mounts. But unfortunately, the request gets fired three times, until it stops. Can you tell me why?

```
 const [rows, setRows] = useState<any[]>([]);
 const [tableReady, setTableReady] = useState<boolean>(false);
 const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);


const getData = async () => {
      const user = await Amplify.Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      const token = user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;
      const apiurl = 'xxx';

      fetch(apiurl, {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: {
                'Authorization': token
           }
      })
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then((result) => {
                setData(result);
           })
           .catch(console.log)
 }

 useEffect(() => {
      if (!tableReady) {
           getData();

           if (data.length > 0) {
                data.forEach((element, i) => {
                     const convertedId: number = +element.id;
                     setRows(rows => [...rows, (createData(convertedId, element.user))]);
                });
                setTableReady(true);
           }
      }
 }, []);

 return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
           <MUIDataTable
                title={""}
                data={rows}
                columns={columns}
           />
      </div>
 );
```

I updated my question due to the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `useEffect` is missing a dependency array, so its callback is invoked every time the component renders.

## Solution

Add a dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!tableReady) {
    getData();

    if (data.length > 0) {
      data.forEach((element, i) => {
        const convertedId: number = +element.id;
        rows.push(convertedId);
      });
      setTableReady(true);
    }
  }
}, []); // <-- dependency array
```

An empty dependency array will run the effect once when the component mounts. If you want it to ran when any specific value(s) update then add these to the dependency array.

See [Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

## Edit

It doesn't appear there is any need to store a `data` state since it's used to populate the `rows` state. Since React state updates are asynchronously processed, and `useEffect` callbacks are 100% synchronous, when you call `getData` and don't wait for the `data` to populate, then the rest of the effect callback is using the initially empty `data` array.

I suggest returning the `fetch` request from `getData` and just process the response data directly into your `rows` state.

```
const getData = async () => {
  const user = await Amplify.Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  const token = user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;
  const apiurl = 'xxx';

  return fetch(apiurl, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': token
    }
  });  
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (!tableReady) {
    getData()
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.length) {
          setRows(data.map(element => createData(+element.id, element.user)))
        }
      })
      .catch(console.error)
      .finally(() => setTableReady(true));
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for your response! That helps a lot. Unfortunately, the data won't get displayed now in the table. I updated the code in my question.

Comment: @mapof I see, the new issue is basically because React updates are asynchronous and you don't wait for `data` state to update when populating `rows` state. Updated answer, please check it out.

Comment: Ah yeah, always these asynchronous calls :D thank, it's working now, this helped.